# How can a Druid get an animal companion?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, animal-companions

I was wondering whether or not there is any non homebrew method other than multi-classing, for a druid character to get an animal companion. If not I would appreciate some advice for implementing the animal companion feature  to the druid class without breaking the game too much.

I am asking because the character I wish to play will be a fire genasi druid who was born to a highly religious family who thought he was a demon or other, and abandoned him in the woods, he was raised by wolves and then trained by a druid, and I want to be able to have a wolf that was different from the others in the pack (a genasi is the result of a genie and a mortal, so does a wolf count as a mortal?) as a companion.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you taken the [tour]? Purple Monkey has already marked it as a duplicate as the other question seems to answer this as written. If you feel it doesn't probably address your concerns you can [edit] your post to give more information. It should be noted that requests for general advice such as "advice for implementing the animal companion feature to the druid class" don't suit this site. Thanks for joining us and happy gaming!

Comment: @PurpleMonkey An animal companion is very different from a trained animal. This is a question about gaining a class feature similar to the beastmaster ranger, on a druid (note that in previous editions, that companion was more of a druid thing than a ranger thing to begin with). Presumably, this would be done as a Druid Circle. My group *also* has this question, as one of the characters is a druid ported from Pathfinder (where she had an animal companion). An answer to the linked question would not answer this one.

Comment: @KRyan check the linked questions of the dupe, or more specifically [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/92073/14878) which is *also* closed as a dupe. If you disagree with these closures then maybe that could be brought up on [meta]? Or maybe an answer should simply be submitted to the ‘trained animal’ Q that *does* cover ways of gaining a class feature similar to the beastmaster ranger since that Q was asked over three years ago, before a lot of the current supplements came out. *shrug*.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey Yes, it looks like the earlier question was an incorrect duplicate. The answer (“there is none” may well have been true of both questions then, or even still be true of both now now, but they aren’t the same question, the answers *could* be different, and may yet become different depending on what gets published. Anyway, I *don’t* have a gold badge for [tag:dnd-5e], so I leave it up to you to sort out a Meta discussion if you like.

Comment: i had an idea about this, i will probably try and find an excuse to have a friend who "happens" to be an awakened wolf, who "happens" to go adventuring with me. Maybe rescue him from a crazy wizard experimenter, or have a freak accident cause a wolf to become awakened, it all works within the rules, and i don't have to worry about multi-classing or homebrew

Comment: @River You might be interested in my recently posted answer to that old question - https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134261/43856 - note that Crawford does use the term "companion" there, as well as gives some rules for scaling up it (like a beast master's companion would), so it might be a better fit to this answer than to that one, as KRyan well mentioned the difference between an animal companion and a simple trained animal.